# How to get the name of currently running app in an App for office 2013

Tags: javascript, html, office-2013, office-app

I am working on app for office 2013, now when i create a project it asks what capabilities do i like this to work for like word, excel, etc... that information is saved in the app manifest and that's fine but how inside the application i can figure out the name of the currently running app like whether it's "Microsoft Word", "Microsoft Excel" how do i get that information via code.

These are the capabilities that i added

```
<Capabilities>
   <Capability Name="Workbook" />
   <Capability Name="Presentation" />
   <Capability Name="Project" />
   <Capability Name="Document" />
</Capabilities>
```

My question is how can i get the current office application using my app with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct interface to get that information, and I'm not sure why you would.

But looking at the Java API For Office 1.1 you find that

- Office.select() is only supported by Word and Excel
- Document.getFileAsync() is only supported by Powerpoint and Word.

So by testing these two for success/failure you can decide that your host is Excel or Word.

Alternatively, you can loop through the script tags to see whether the document includes `excel-xy.js` or `word-xy.js`.